# Adobe Air Version 3.0 + causing applicationUpdater to misbehave

Tags: air, adobe

Adobe Flex/Flash Builder 4 question.  I have a flex app built on AIR version 2.02 and sdk 3.3
now updating to sdk 4.0 and AIR version 3.0
the ApplicationUpdater section does not display anything with AIR version 3.0, but it does with AIR version 2.2
both using sdk 4.0 for the flashbuilder code. 
anyone seen this and found an answer?

thanks
Dave